# How does hyperledger fabric handle random number generation?

Tags: random, hyperledger

Given that one can write chaincode in JavaScript or Go and freely call random methods provided by the language libraries, how does the network handle the randomness?

Answer (score 1):

Hyperledger fabric works in the order of **Execute Order and Validate**.So Execution steps is done in **Endorser** so execution is done with endorsement policy which is defined and it also removes randomization to avoid statelessness.

Next the Ordering of transaction is done with the help of **Orderer**.

Finally Validation is done with the **committer** to avoid double spending.This is basically to check the integrity of the transaction.

Comment: Can you please give me some more resources, to read up on the topic?

Comment: https://medium.com/swlh/hyperledger-chapter-6-hyperledger-fabric-components-technical-context-767985f605dd @Shocky2
Read the medium articles to get more insights on this